# kernel 3.2.0-30-generic, doesn't support raedon ati drivers, Why?

Tags: ati, kernel

I upgraded my kernel to 3.2.0-30-generic. Since the new kernel install my ati drivers are no more supported. I've tried reinstalling the ati drivers manually. But the process doesn't seem to help.

I am using amd raedon : 6400 series 1Gb graphic card.
I have been following this link previously:-

[Correct way to install ati drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513)

Please provide your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Ati drivers works fine on my pc. Try purge drivers to default ones

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Then try use this steps http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/install-amd-catalyst-128-on-ubuntu.html. That worked for me fine. I had also some problems with the way of installing you linked here.

Comment: thanks, i haven't been able to install the driver from the mentioned link.